# Angular trying to add totals on the fly, not currently working

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently displaying questions and based on your selected answer the question score shows up on the right. That works but what I can't figure out is how to auto-update the SubTotal. Trying an ng-change on the select drop down but it doesn't seem to work. I orignaly tried to somehow bind sub-total to a ng-model but wasn't sure how best to do that.
Right now I'm trying to use a call on ng-change to "optionChange" to update the value but it's not updating in the UI or firing off the alert.

HTML

```
<td class="control-label input-lg">{{question.title}}</td>
    <td>
        <select data-ng-model="question.selectedOption" data-ng-change="vm.optionChange"
                ng-options="option.name for option in question.options" class="form-control input-lg">
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><span class="input-lg">{{question.selectedOption.value}}</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="control-label input-lg">Sub-Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="input-lg">{{vm.sections[0].subTotal}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Controller

(function () {
    'use strict';

```
var controllerId = 'default';

// TODO: replace app with your module name
angular.module('scoreCard').controller(controllerId,
    ['$scope', controller1]);

function controller1($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.questions = [
        {
            title: "Question 1",
            section: 1,
            options: [
                { name: "Option 1", value: 5 },
                { name: "Option 2", value: 2.5 },
                { name: "Option 3: 0 }
            ],
            selectedOption: {name:"", value:0}
        },
        {
            title: "Question 2",
            section: 1,
            options: [
                { name: "Option 1", value: 5 },
                { name: "Option 2", value: 2.5 },
                { name: "Option 3: 0 }
            ],
            selectedOption: { name: "", value: 0 }
        }
    ];

    vm.sections = [
        { name: "section1", subTotal: 0 },
        { name: "section2", subTotal: 0 }

    ];

    vm.optionChange = function () {
        vm.sections[0].subTotal = vm.questions[0].selectedOption.value + vm.questions[1].selectedOption.value;
    alert('test');
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. So ridiculous.

Had to change

```
data-ng-change="vm.optionChange"
```

to

```
data-ng-change="vm.optionChange()"
```

Answer (score 2):

$watches are not needed in this case. Just in case somebody wants to play with this some, here's a jsFiddle for it which fixes some issues with the JSON in the code above and works pretty well:

http://jsfiddle.net/BHA9C/

I chose to change the reference to the summed value to an actual function which calculates it and returns the summed value:

```
 <td><span class="input-lg">{{ subTotalForSection(0) }}</span></td>
```

And I put added the function which does the summing:

```
$scope.subTotalForSection = function (section) {
    // Save off the value (presumably for later use).
    $scope.sections[section].subTotal = $scope.questions[0].selectedOption.value + $scope.questions[1].selectedOption.value;

    // Return it for display.
    return $scope.sections[section].subTotal;
};
```

Comment: This is pretty nice here, didn't think about calling a function directly in a placeholder on the page. Nice

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to call `optionChange` when `question.selectedOption` changes, try this within your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('question.selectedOption', vm.optionChange);
```

Tried my best to understand your question.

I'm also assuming `vm` is attached to your controller `$scope`. The code snippet doesn't make that clear.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on vm.question[0].selectedOption but doesn't fire. I'll update the question to include the top of the controller. I'm using the controller as feature

Comment: Ok I've tried.. $scope.$watch('question.selectedOption', vm.optionChange); $scope.$watch('vm.questions.selectedOption', vm.optionChange); and $scope.$watch('vm.questions[0].selectedOption', vm.optionChange);  I tossed in an alert in there too, not firing.

Comment: You're assumption was correct on what I'm trying to do, updated the question to more clearly state it. trying to fire off the optionChange to add up the subtotal of points but open to other suggestions as I can't get it to fire.